# How does taking the logarithm of negative numbers compare to taking logarithm of positive numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Is this an accurate statement:  The logarithm of negative number is not unique but the logarithm of a positive number is unique. I know the first clause is true but I'm not sure if it applies to positive numbers as well.

Comment: for positive reals you just take ***the*** logarithm. This "principal branch" of the logarithm extends nicely to the complex numbers minus $0$ and minus the negative reals, but gives inconsistent results (limits) at the negative reals and gives gibberish at $0$

Answer (score 3):

A positive real number has a unique real logarithm, but infinitely many complex valued logarithms. If $x>0$, then
$$
\log x+2\,k\,\pi\,i,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z},
$$
where $\log x$ is the unique real logarithm of $x$, are logarithms of $x$:
$$
e^{\log x+2\,k\,\pi\,i}=x,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The "branch cut" is generally taken to exclude the negative real axis, which is why you may think the log of a negative real number is not unique. You can take whichever branch cut you like.

Answer (score 1):

If $e^a=5$ then $e^{a\pm2\pi i} = 5$ and $e^{a\pm4\pi i} = 5$, etc., so in a sense $a+n\pi i$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ are all logarithms of $5$.  However, with positive numbers the choice $n=0$ is natural; with negative numbers one can say $e^{a\pm\pi i} = -5$ but the choice between $\text{“}+\text{''}$ and $\text{“}-\text{''}$ is arbitrary.

Just how to define "natural" in this context is an interesting question.  If there's an appropriate way to define it, maybe one could *prove* it's natural, and then we could argue about whether the definition is the “right” one.